# crystal reports: how can I have both indent settings and html text interpretation

Tags: html, crystal-reports, indentation

I am using crystal report for reporting data in my windows application. In that there is one field in which whole HTML text will come and display in the report.

Now i want to display some of the text in following format :

```
1) abc text
    a) abc text details
        i) this is sample text.this is sample text.this is sample text.this is sample 
           text.this is sample text.this is sample text.
        ii)this is sample text.this is sample text.this is sample text.this is sample 
           text.this is sample text.this is sample text. 
2) efg text
   a) abc text details
        i) this is sample text.this is sample text.this is sample text.this is sample 
           text.this is sample text.this is sample text.
        ii)this is sample text.this is sample text.this is sample text.this is sample 
           text.this is sample text.this is sample text.
```

So can anyone tell me how do indentations on this type of text?

Comment: Which version of Crystal Reports are you using?

Comment: We are using Crystal Report v13.0.2000.0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, CR supports the following html tags:

```
html
body
div (causes a paragraph break)
tr (causes only a paragraph break; does not preserve column structure of a table)
span
font
p (causes a paragraph break)
br (causes a paragraph break)
h1 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & twice default size)
h2 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 1.5 times default size)
h3 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 9/8 default size)
h4 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold)
h5 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 5/6 default size)
h6 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 5/8 default size)
center
big (increases font size by 2 points)
small (decreases font size by 2 points if it's 8 points or larger)
b
i
s
strike
u
The supported HTML attributes are:
align
face
size
color
style
font-family
font-size
font-style
font-weight
```

In Crystal Reports 2008 Service Pack 2 and above, the following additional HTML tags and attributes have been added to the supported list:
The supported HTML tags are:

```
ul  ( bulleted list )
ol  ( ordered list )
li   ( tag defining a list item used for both list type: ul and ol. )
Note: The bullet will not show up as a regular size bullet, but a small dot.
```

The supported HTML attributes are:

```
strong ( bold )
```

If that doesn't satisfy your needs, you could always convert the html field to a rich text field, which will give you a little more flexibility.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: That i know. but how to solve the my problem that is my question.

Comment: Actually, that would be the <ol> tag because they are not bullets, but numbered/lettered lists.